# Libgdx could not determine java version 11.0.1

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I tried everything I installed every possible Java file a million times I installed the newest gradle version but it continues to show this error. I'm on Mac. Please help thanks

Comment: It might not support Java 11 (has no backward capability), try it out with the Java 8

Comment: You can update the Gradle version to 4.6. Look for the properties file in the Gradle wrapper directory. LibGDX defaults to an older Gradle version to maintain compatibility with some libraries so keep that in mind if you start using libraries.

Answer (score 11):

IF you do not want to develop for Android Java 11 works fine libgdx.

You have to change some things before everything builds and runs.
Here's what I did to get my project working.
My context Mac OSX 10.14 and `openJDK 11.0.2`, new project, Desktop launcher and a bunch of Extensions (not important).

1. The error you get about not being able to find java 11.0.x comes from gradle. Java 11 is only supported since gradle 5. In order to use gradle 5 instead of 4.6 the generated project is configured with, go to `<project-dir>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` into `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip`.

That resolves the java 11 error just to confront you with a new error `Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.`

2. To get rid of that, open `<project-dir>/desktop/build.gradle` and change line 27 (might be different for you)
   `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)` into
   `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)`

   thats `classesDir` into `classesDirs`

This should resolve all build errors and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I am strongly recommend to use Java version not greater than 8. It is many incompatibility issues I faced just on 9 version of JDK in Android Dev environment.

Uninstall all java you have, use this article, because it is not as such easy without knowledge: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

After download the 8th version from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

I did same some time ago and all problems left