# How to upgrade gradle wrapper version for LibGDX

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, libgdx

I'm trying to generate a new LibGDX project for Kotlin for IntelliJ IDEA. I'm using Java 12. When I click generate it comes up with the error: `Could not determine Java version from '12'`. In the advanced settings I have "IDEA" and "Use Kotlin" ticked.

Apparently this means you have to upgrade your Gradle wrapper version. I have tried opening the generated folder in IntelliJ and changing `distributionUrl` to the 5.3.1 Gradle version. But this fails with `Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.`

Gradle version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-03-28 09:09:23 UTC
Revision:     f2fae6ba563cfb772c8bc35d31e43c59a5b620c3

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          12 (Oracle Corporation 12+33)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Jun 09 23:06:52 EDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.3.1-bin.zip
```

I've done some research but I don't understand what most of the answers are telling me to do. I'm completely unfamiliar with gradle.

Am I not correctly upgrading the gradle wrapper version or is IntelliJ's gradle wrapper simply incompatible with java 12?

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012160/104891)? Does it help?

Comment: Somehow that evaded my radar. Thanks that fixed my problem.